# Using sed / grep to add / insert code before </script> tag

Tags: awk, sed

How can I insert commands before the `</script>` tag using sed?

Example: 
Currently looks like

```
</script>
```

After I would like it to look like:

```
var result = runFuntion();
alert(result)
</script>
```

I was trying to use `echo 'xyz </script> foo' | sed 's/\(foo\)/bar\1/g'`

But the `</script>` tag produces issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
echo '</script>' | sed 's|</script>|var result = runFuntion();\nalert(result)\n</script>|'
```

or

```
echo '</script>' | sed 's|\(</script>\)|var result = runFuntion();\nalert(result)\n\1|'
```

Output:

```
var result = runFuntion();
alert(result)
</script>
```

---

I switched from `s///` to `s|||`.

Comment: or shorter: `sed 's|</script>|var result = runFuntion();\nalert(result)\n&|'` :)

Comment: `sed 's|</script>|var result = runFuntion();\nalert(result)\n&|'<<<'</script>'`

Answer (score 0):

In case you prepared a longer piece of code and don't want to reformat/escape it directly in the sed expression, you can also import it from a file. Assuming there is nothing (other than spaces) on the line before `</script>` and you have a file `extension.js` containing :

```
var result = runFuntion();
alert(result);
```

then you can use this (GNU sed) :

```
echo '</script>' | sed '/^\s*<\/script>/ e cat extension.js'
```